# If $X$ is connected then it is not the union of disjoint, nonempty, separated sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that if $X$ is connected (not the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets), the $X$ is not the union of two disjoint nonempty separated sets (two sets $A$ and $B$ which do not contain any limit points of one another.

My try was this:Suppose by way of contradiction that $X$ is connected and the union of two disjoint nonempty separated sets $A,B$. Then $A \cap \overline{B}=\overline{A} \cap B=\varnothing$. But then $X-\overline{A},X-\overline{B}$ are two disjoint nonempty open sets with union $X$. So $X$ is not connected a contradiction.

Would this be the right way to do this problem?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In fact $X-\bar A=B,X-\bar B=A$